# Is there any difference in the default text alignment between document classes book, report, article, and so on?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, article, report

I've come to the question if there are differences in the text alignments regarding the document classes.

I'm trying to justify a text in my whole document (report). Reading question I came to the notion that the article class is justified by default, so I wanted either to know what the other document classes defaults are, or at least the report document class default.

Comment: I hate to say this: but this question is silly.  In the time it took you to type your question into this website, you could have typed it in to latex and hit compile and observe that it is indeed justified.  Don't take my word for it.  Try it! :)

Comment: All document classes you mention (specifically the default ones, but mostly others as well) have a default "justified" alignment. If you're not seeing that, then something is up.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Comment: The answer to your question is "no" but unfortunately the system doesn't allow two letter answers. Why would you think they are different?

Comment: I can only guess that the OP used `\abstract{<abstract>}` but who can be sure? I vote to close as unclear.